# Change values according to other variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a quite large data set with sales information. Some of these have negative `salesvalue` (credit note). I need to connect these credit note to the original sales note, and at the same time keep the original sales date. There is no single variable indicating which sales note the credit note belongs to, so I have to identify where all other variables are equal.

Example data:

```
data <- data.frame(number = 1:4,               
                   Date=c("02-01-2022", "06-01-2022", "07-01-2022", "06-01-2022"),
                   state = c("filet", "filet", "whole", "filet"),
                   specie = c("haddock", "cod", "haddock", "cod"),
                   salesvalue= c(300,500,200,-400),
                   salesdate=c("01-01-2022", "05-01-2022", "06-01-2022", "12-01-2022"))
data  

#  number       Date state  specie value  salesdate
#      1 02-01-2022 filet haddock   300 01-01-2022
#      2 06-01-2022 filet     cod   500 05-01-2022
#      3 07-01-2022 whole haddock   200 06-01-2022
#      4 06-01-2022 filet     cod  -400 12-01-2022
```

I want to change `salesdate` of `salesvalue < 0` to `salesdate` where `salesvalue > 0` and everything else equal, and aggregate them.

In this case I want to change `salesdate` of number 4 from "12-01-2022" to "05-01-2022" (same as 2 where all other values are equal).

This is what I tried:

```
datanew <- data %>% 
  group_by(Date, state, specie, value) %>% 
  mutate(date_sale=if_else(value < 0, 
         first(salesdate[value>0]), salesdate)) %>% 
  group_by(Date, state, specie, value, salesdate, date_sale) %>% 
  summarise(value_new=sum(value))

 
datanew 

# Date       state specie  value salesdate  date_sale  value_new
  <chr>      <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>          <dbl>
# 02-01-2022 filet haddock   300 01-01-2022 01-01-2022       300
# 06-01-2022 filet cod      -400 12-01-2022 NA              -400
# 06-01-2022 filet cod       500 05-01-2022 05-01-2022       500
# 07-01-2022 whole haddock   200 06-01-2022 06-01-2022       200
```

But it doesn't solve my problem. I have no I idea how to fix this, and would appreciate any suggestions!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check if this works for you: Cave: It may strongly on the original data!

The idea is to bring the data in position by grouping and arranging:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(Date, state, specie) %>% 
  arrange(salesvalue, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(salesdate = ifelse(salesvalue < 0, lead(salesdate), salesdate)) %>% 
  arrange(number)
```

```
  number Date       state specie  salesvalue salesdate 
   <int> <chr>      <chr> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>     
1      1 02-01-2022 filet haddock        300 01-01-2022
2      2 06-01-2022 filet cod            500 05-01-2022
3      3 07-01-2022 whole haddock        200 06-01-2022
4      4 06-01-2022 filet cod           -400 05-01-2022
```

Comment: Both of these works for my example data. But not my real data where I have many more variables to group by. The salesdate change for the selected variables, but to a random date (as far as I can see).. am I using dplyr the wrong way? I have tried to changing the order of the variables, and cuttting down the number of variables to an absolute minium, but it doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rows_update()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter(salesvalue >= 0) %>%
  select(-c(number, salesvalue)) %>%
  rows_update(data, ., by = c("Date", "state", "specie"))

#   number       Date state  specie salesvalue  salesdate
# 1      1 02-01-2022 filet haddock        300 01-01-2022
# 2      2 06-01-2022 filet     cod        500 05-01-2022
# 3      3 07-01-2022 whole haddock        200 06-01-2022
# 4      4 06-01-2022 filet     cod       -400 05-01-2022
```

Another choice:

```r
data %>%
  filter(salesvalue >= 0) %>%
  select(-c(number, salesvalue), x = salesdate) %>%
  left_join(data, .) %>%
  mutate(salesdate = ifelse(salesvalue < 0, x, salesdate)) %>%
  select(-x)
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe you added another version first (below)? That worked for me on the example data. This last edit didn't work on my data. data %>%
  filter(salesvalue >= 0) %>%
  select(-c(number, salesvalue), x = salesdate) %>%
  left_join(data, .) %>%
  mutate(salesdate = ifelse(salesvalue < 0, x, salesdate)) %>%
  select(-x)

Comment: @findus I recover it back. The two versions work dependent on your data. If anyone has solved your question, you can consider accepting it by clicking the check mark. Thanks!